# Html compiler and life cycle

Tags: html

Hi Professionals,

1. Can anybody explain the HTML life cycle.
2. I want to make sure is there any compiler available to compile HTML files.

I tried to find online. But no luck I could not find anything in online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. From a client-server point of view? or a client browser-parsing point of view? or from a specific language event triggering point of view (i.e. asp.net)?

   I'll take a guess at the first. This would be

   - Client person "requests" a webpage. For example, you open a web browser, enter http://www.microsoft.com/ & hit enter.
   - (Ignoring the protocols & hardware & DNS discussion here), the request gets sent over the internet to a server hosting this website. This server will have a "home page" configured. I.e. it'll have a setting which says "if anyone requests Microsoft.com, give them the Microsoft.com/homepage.html file".
   - This file is then sent back to the client computer & the browser renders the content for the end user to see.

---

2. HTML is a "markup language" - it's for describing content and structure only, it's not a programming language (it doesn't have if/branching statements, loops, methods etc.).

   Only programming languages have compilers or interpreters in order to turn human readable statements into binary 1's & 0's to be executed in RAM & on the CPU. HTML is never converted in this manner, it is just read as-is.

   What happens is your web browser (Internet Explorer, FireFox, Safari etc.) "reads" (or parses) the HTML document structure & content then outputs this to the screen in a more human presentable format (i.e. it'll might see   and  tags and draw a table and its rows onscreen so you see it similar to an Excel file etc.)

Comment: Alex@ - do not get me wrong. This is one of interview question. The interviewer asked me this one. I said no need to compile html file. Have you ever heard about html compiler?

Comment: HTML by its very nature cannot and will not ever be compiled. If there is a "html compiler" out there, it's probably a hoax, joke or virus. Best of luck with getting the new job then too!

Comment: Yes I agree with you! That's what i told him. But he strongly refused my word so only i asked this stupidity question here! Thanks man